# Não consigo incluir componentes no react

Tags: javascript, react

## Problema com React

Olá, tento fazer um import semelhante ao include de um header, mas estou com grandes dificuldades. O terminal indica que nunca usei o "topo", mesmo que eu tenha usado como componente

### Veja:

#### Arquivo 1

```
import './App.css';
import {topo} from './components/screenComponents';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <topo/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

#### Arquivo 2

```
const topo = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <header id="header" className="cabecalho">
                            <div className="imgs-logos">
                                <img src="img/logo-meta-d.png" alt="logo-w" id="logo-d" className="esconder"/>
                                <img src="img/logo-meta-m.png" alt="logo-w" id="logo-m"/>
                            </div>
                            <nav className="nav">
                                <ul className="lista">
                                    <li className="item esconder"><a href="/#" title="" className="ancora">Vantagens</a></li>
                                    <li className="item esconder"><a href="/#" title="" className="ancora">Sobre</a></li>
                                    <li className="item esconder"><a href="/#" title="" className="ancora">Baixar</a></li>
                                    <li className="item"><a href="/#" title="" className="ancora">Mobile</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </header>
        </div>
        );
}

export default topo;
```

Comment: é que você exportou por padrão ou `default` então a importação é `import topo from './components/screenComponents';` apesar que eu não vi o diretório do seu código então basicamente é o estou vendo na sua pergunta.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma e não consigo importar o componente da mesma forma, teria outra solução!?

Answer (score 0):

A função não pode ser exportada como `default` e ser chamada dessa forma.

Você deve exportar dessa forma:

```
export {Topo}
```

E importar dessa forma:

```
import {Topo} from ''./components/screenComponents'';
```

Outra coisa muito importante, no meu um componente só é realmente exibido quando ele Inicia em letra maiúscula!

> O React trata componentes começando com letras minúsculas como tags do
> DOM. Por exemplo, `<div />` representa uma tag div do HTML, mas `<Topo />` representa um componente.
>
> você pode ver mais sobre [aqui](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

No meu, após essas modificações, tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Explicando de forma bem simplista.

Como no arquivo de definição do componente você exportou como 'default', ao importá-lo você deve fazer da seguinte forma:

```
import topo from './components/screenComponents';
```

A forma que você está importando funciona quando o componente não é exportado como 'default'.